# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}{\exp(A \cos(x))dx}, \int_0^{2\pi}{\exp(A \cos(x) + B \sin(x))dx}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I saw that
$$\int_0^\pi{\exp(A \cos(x))dx} = \pi I_0(A) $$

I am trying to understand what would be the solution for the following two integrals :

$$
\begin{split}
&\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(A \cos(x)\right)dx \\
&\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(A \cos(x) + B \sin(x)\right)dx
\end{split}
$$

I anticipate that this might come interms of Bessels functions, I am clueless on how to proceed with the known solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using your first result, you get $\int_0^{2\pi} \exp (A\cos(x))\text dx = \pi(I_0(A) + I_0(-A))$ by splitting the integral in two.

Comment: @SolubleFish And, because $I_0$ is even this is just $2\pi I_0(A)$..

Comment: $A\cos(x) + B\sin(x) = a\cos(x+b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember SolubleFish's comment:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(s\cos t)\mathrm dt=2\pi I_0(s)$$
Now, note that
$$x\cos t+y\sin t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\cos\left(t-\arctan(y/x)\right)$$
([proof](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-rcostheta-alpha-2009-1.pdf)) therefore
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(x\cos t +y\sin t)\mathrm dt \\ =\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\cos(t-\arctan(y/x))\right)\mathrm dt$$
But due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of the integrand, we can replace $t-...$ by just $t$:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(x\cos t+y\sin t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\cos t\right)\mathrm dt=2\pi I_0\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
Done.

Comment: [Verified by Wolfram.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bx*Cos%5Bt%5D%2By*Sin%5Bt%5D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2*pi%7D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

$Acos(x)+Bsin(x)=Ccos(x-a)$.  Get $C$ from $Ccos(a)=A$ and $Csin(a)=B$.  Second integral=$2\pi(I_0(C))$.